# What if the sum of the elements of the inverse of a matrix is 0

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

If the sum of the elements of an inverse of a matrix $A$ is $0$, does it affect somehow the determinant or something else of the matrix $A$, where $A$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix?

I tried for a $2\times 2$ matrix, and I get that also the sum of the elements of the matrix A is also $0$, but I do not know if it applies for any  $n\times n$ matrix.

Answer (score 2):

This is not even true for a $2 \times 2$ matrix, take
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
2 & 3 
\end{pmatrix}, \quad A^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
-3 & 2 \\
2 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Ah alright,I am sorry for the mistake than.

Comment: But there is another propriety that gets from the fact that the sum of the elements of the invers of a matrix is 0?

Comment: @mathgirl I don't think so. The sum of all elements of a matrix is not a very natural object.